# Is there such a thing as result cache for Informix

Tags: informix

Informix has SSC (SQL Statement Cache), but that doesn't seem to cache the result of the query.

Is there something else to activate to also cache the result ?

I am using Informix 12.1 on Redhat.

Comment: Succinctly, no.  Perhaps the nearest is the page buffer pool, which isn't precisely the result of a query, but for some queries keeps the relevant data in memory rather than requiring access to the disk.  There are issues with statement result caches.  The result for a given query might be different for different users.  If there are parameters to the query, the results in the cache must be for the same parameter values.  There's also the thought "why are you asking the same question over and over — you expect the same answer, don't you?"